# PHP max file limit

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a file upload system which, in PHP, limits to 20 files at once, even though I select 25-30 files it only uploads 20. I would like to know why this problem exists and if there is a fix to this either from php.ini or from anywhere.

Comment: Is it so hard to open php.ini and search for any upload related configuration? `max_file_uploads` is what you need to change.

Comment: i actually looked for that and it wasn't in my php.ini but I just added.. If you posted as answer I would select it. Anyways, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change **max_file_uploads** to whatever value you like in your php.ini. but beware of few gotchas

**max_file_uploads** counts empty upload fields as if they were being used

there is a [good article](http://allinthehead.com/retro/349/the-curse-of-max_file_uploads) on this that you should read

Comment: I knew it would count, therefore I have only one file box which has the attribute multiple, meaning whatever you select is counted as file, otherwise... nothing happens.

Comment: I just thought I should make you aware. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

what version of PHP are you using? If there was no `max_file_uploads` inside your php.ini, you may be using old version that does not support this configuration directive, so adding it should not change anything.

Other thing that can limit number of files uploaded is `suhosin.upload.max_uploads` if your server is running with suhosin extension.