# PHP file input number limited to 20

Tags: php, file-upload

I have multiple file uploads but the `$_FILES` seems to be chunked after 20 inputs

```
var_dump($_FILES); //gives array(20){ ... } although there are more file inputs
```

This is the public [php_info](http://90plan.ovh.net/infos/test.php53/)

Which parameter is responsible for this limit ?

As a **workaround**, I used some javascript:

```
    <input id="input_fileXX" type="file" class="input_file">
----
    $('.input_file').on('change',function(){
        $(this).prop('name',$(this).prop('id'));
    });
```

This allows to only send the inputs that have change. This is useful when you can't change php.ini.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339759/php-max-file-limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

> Since PHP 5.2.12, the [max_file_uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) configuration setting acts as a limit on the number of files that can be uploaded in one request. You will need to ensure that your form does not try to upload more files in one request than this limit.

Comment: Thank you, now I see. I will update my question with a workaround I used. Thanks